# Is there a better way to say "the highest possible"

Tags: expressions

Here is the sentence I am trying to improve:

"How building a culture of Quality results in better care and the highest possible reimbursement revenue."

Seems clunky but I'm a bit stuck. Suggestions?

Comment: It's not a sentence yet. You probably need to add more information to give us a more complete idea of what you want to say. Is this the title of an article?

Comment: There probably are some different ways to phrase it, but how can we objectively know if those ways are "better"?

Comment: "You're the Top!" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6oGytt0Hiw

Comment: This is a bullet point in a list of what will be discussed in a webinar.

Comment: To start with, you might want to replace "*highest possible*" with "*highest*" (or "*greatest*" or whatever). The impossible cases can usually be excluded as uninteresting to consider.

Answer (score 5):

... and **maximizes** reimbursement revenue.

> make as large or great as possible.
>   "the company was aiming to maximize profits"

Here I'm not just substituting for "the highest possible" (i.e. an adjective), I'm substituting for "*results in* the highest possible" (i.e. a verb).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like *[maximal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/maximal)*

> Of or constituting a maximum; the highest or greatest possible:
> *the maximal speed*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

> You could say *How building a culture of Quality results in better care and maximal reimbursement revenue.*

Answer (score 1):

How about *the* ***[utmost](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/utmost)*** *reimbursement revenue*.

> **Utmost:** Of the highest or greatest degree, amount, or intensity; most extreme: *a matter of the utmost importance.*

thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score -1):

**Acme** which means the highest point of something. It's usually used to refer to metaphorical heights rather than literal ones, for example on dictionary.com:

> The empire was at the *acme* of its power.

or on Merriam-Webster.com:

> His fame was at its *acme*.

So you'd be looking at "How building a culture of Quality results in better care and the acme of reimbursement revenue."

Comment: I believe this is the wrong part of speech for the job. This sentence, more than likely, needs an adjective. *Acme* is a noun.